# Disable all Jenkins jobs from a given Jenkins View / Tab

Tags: groovy, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

I have around 100-120 jobs in one of the view called "Gradle Deploys" that I created in Jenkins. How can I disable all the jobs from Jenkins only from a given View / tab.

I tried the following groovy syntax to first just show all the jobs in a given view but it errors out.

```
jenkins = Hudson.instance

//The following works actually but gives a lot of info.
//println "----" + jenkins.instance.getView("Gradle Deploys").items

println "----" + jenkins.instance.getView("Gradle Deploys").items.each.getItems().print(it)
```

Once I get the list of just job names in a given view, I just have to use ".disable()" function in the above command and it'll work.

If I use the following code, it does what I want, but I'm looking for a one liner.

```
for (item in jenkins.instance.getView("Gradle Deploys").items) {
   println("\nJob: $item.name")
   item.disabled=true

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Tim for his solution. I'm adding/enhancing it a bit further:

```
jenkins.instance.getView("Gradle Deploys").items*.disabled = true
```

But if you want to print something out at the same time, you'll need an each

```
    jenkins = Hudson.instance

    jenkins.instance.getView("Gradle Deploys").items.each { item ->
    println "\nJob: $item.name"
    item.disabled = true
}
```

Now, the above examples works perfectly if you try to run them from "Script Console" but it errors out if you try to create/run it as a Scriptler script (as shown below).

See: The above code works in Script Console view in Jenkins (When you click Manage Jenkins > Script Console). To get this, you may need the plugin installed.

[image]

Now, the same script didn't work when I tried to create a Scripter Script and ran it that way. This requires Scriptler Plugin installed.

[image]

To Solve the above error message (as shown in the Scriptler Script - window), you need to enter another line (at top).

Final script looks like (NOTE: Value of viewName variable will be provided by the Scriptler parameter and it'll overwrite whatever you'll mention in the script itself):

//The following line is necessary if you are running the script/code via a "Scriptler Script" script way.
//This way you can prompt a user to provide parameters (for ex: viewName) and use it to disable job in that view only.

```
import hudson.model.*

jenkins = Hudson.instance

println ""
println "--- Disabling all jobs in view: ${viewName}"
println ""

jenkins.instance.getView(viewName).items*.disabled = true

//Now the above will disable it but you still need to save it. Otherwise, you'll loose your changes (of disabling the jobs) after each Jenkins restart.
jenkins.instance.getView(viewName).items.each { item -> item.save() }
```

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: viewName for class: Script1

Comment: @Lalle if you see my answer above, you have to set i.e. var = "some name" or pass it to groovy script a variable name viewName that the code line is expecting 

In scriptler plugin a UI interface was there but they may have deprecated that plugin so you can just pass that variable to groovy file or just set a view name in variable viewName inside .groovy

Answer (score 15):

You should be able to just disable them all with:

```
jenkins.instance.getView("Gradle Deploys").items*.disabled = true
```

But if you want to print something out at the same time, you'll need an `each`

```
jenkins.instance.getView("Gradle Deploys").items.each { item ->
    println "\nJob: $item.name"
    item.disabled = true
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use each in the first command (one-liner) if I don't want to show/echo anything?

Comment: You shouldn't need to the first command should disable all the items as is

Comment: I have updated the answer to support both "Script Console" and "Scriptler" way of running the script. Otherwise, it gave me an error when I tried the code (which worked successfully in Script Console Window in Jenkins) as a Scriptler script way.

Comment: Do you see a bug there?

Answer (score 2):

```
Jenkins.instance.getView("Gradle Deploys").items*.disabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the solution from AKS to something like below allows to disable all the jobs within the folder.

```
Jenkins.instance.getView("all").items.each { item -> 
  println "\nJob: $item"
  if (item.class == com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) {
    item.items.each { subitem ->
      println "\nJob: $subitem"
      subitem.disabled = true
    }
  } else {
    item.disabled = true
  }
}
```

Here, "all" in the first line can be replaced with a specific view name, else it will disable all the jobs in the Jenkins server.